# Как получить pivot таблицу?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблицы:
**customer**

```
id name
 1 Nick  
 2 Bob  
 3 John
```

**item**

```
id type   price
 1 Ball     20  
 2 Flower   20  
 3 Circle   10
```

**result**

```
id customer_id item_id
 1      1         1  
 2      2         2  
 3      3         1  
 4      1         1
```

Нужно получить данные в виде:

```
Ball Flower Circle  <= вид товара  
 2      -     -     <=  а это отчет по каждому пользователю, в данном случае
                        Nick купил товар (1) 2 раза  
 -      1     -     <= а Bob купил товар (2) 1 раз, другие товары -  
 1      -     -
```

Comment: Т.е. в столбцах у Вас вид товара? И если у вас 100 видов товара, то Вы хотите получить 100 столбцов?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Да, это для отчета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @sql_dynamic = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF(item_id = ', item_id,', 1, 0)) AS ', item_name)) 
    FROM (SELECT id AS item_id, type AS item_name  FROM `item` AS innerT ORDER BY id ASC) AS itemsT);
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT customer_id,', @sql_dynamic, ' FROM result GROUP BY customer_id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Вся идея здесь [Dynamic Pivot Table Using MySQL – Simple Logic](http://webdevzoom.com/dynamic-pivot-table-using-mysql/)