# Подскажите какие запросы можно сделать с IF(),CASE,к БД Спортивная Атлетика

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Нужно сделать 10 сложных запросов,с IF(),CASE,или же вложенные.Я сделал 3,но нету фантазии какие сделать еще
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зависимость средних пожертвований спонсоров на игру от дня недели игры, по месяцам. На выходе таблица по вертикали идут месяцы игры, по горизонтали 7 колонок по дням недели в который средний price за этот день недели в этом месяце

Comment: @Mike Я не знаю как найти средний price за этот день недели в этом месяце,и как сделать 7 колонок по дням?Надо в select писать дни в запятых? И у меня дата начала игры,и спонсор просто донатит на игру.Я просто не понимаю как это сделать?Может есть какие-то полегче варианты?

Comment: Ну тут как раз IF был нужен что бы при группировке по месяцу собрать avg(price) по отдельности для каждого дня недели. Собственно if/case в основном нужен именно для вариантов в которых в колонку должны попасть не все данные группы, а только определенная часть из них. типа как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690405/194569

Comment: @Mike то мне надо переделать тот пример?

Comment: Я просто не представляю в каком случае в "достаточно простом" запросе мог бы понадобится if/case. И никто кроме вашего учителя не знает, что является "сложным" запросом с точки тех знаний по sql, которые входят в вашу программу. А потому этот вопрос здесь абсолютно бесполезен.

Comment: @Mike А не подскажите как сделать как в том примере,то есть по горизонтале назва соревнований по вертикале Фамилия спортсмена,и должно показывать какое место занял спортсмен на этих соревнованиях

Comment: как в том примере ни как. все столбцы должны быть объявлены в запросе при его создании. а заранее названия соревнований все неизвестны. Единственный путь - это создавать запрос динамически на основе данных https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/717514/194569

Comment: @Mike У меня получилось так сделать